# How to add a background image to an email?

Tags: background, e-mail

Is there a way to add a background image to an email and ensure it will display in all email clients?

Comment: This is not a Graphic design question.

Comment: I think this is off-topic since it has more to do with HTML/Knowing Email Clients than with Graphic Design(e.g. creating the Image)

Comment: To one part? To the whole email? What email clients are giving you the most trouble? What type of layout are you using?

Comment: Suggestion:  Visit sites like MailChimp's, where you'll find lots of good information and advice as to what works across a broad range of email clients. And accept that some people prefer text-only email and may reject the HTML email you'd need to pull this off.  Their in-box, their rules. The "done thing" is to provide a text-only version of your email for those who want it.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [backgrounds.cm](https://backgrounds.cm/) generator.

Note the radio buttons below **`Apply background image to:`**

- Full email body *`for the email background`*
- A single table cell *`background for a single element within the email`*

I would include the code, but there are a few variations depending on what size options you want, so I'd advice to just use the website to generate the code.

Answer (score -2):

You must use HTML 
Hope to see the links below to help you

- https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_full_page.asp
- http://tedgoas.github.io/Cerberus/

Comment: Hello Morteza, could you please explain a bit more what we'll find behind the link you provide and why it answers the question? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and keep contributing!